# Expose 1 Spring Boot Actuator endpoint via HTTP while others via HTTPS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Is it possible to expose only 1 specific Actuator endpoint (say, `/health`) via HTTP while others will be behind HTTPS?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, is there a configuration option to set this? If not, is there other workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: just a shot in the dark: have you tried [something like this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3509)?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe with Spring security? This is an interesting question